# How to split the array into two subarrays with the smallest sum difference?

Tags: sorting, search-algorithms, binary-search

Given

- An array of elements, all elements are positive (unsorted, but sorting is not a problem if required)

The objective:

- To create two subarrays, so that `abs(sum(array_1) - sum(array_2))` is the **smallest** possible

The order of elements in the subarrays and the amount of elements don't matter but **all elements should be used**

E.g.

> Input: Starting Array = {5, 8, 13, 27, 14} 
> Result: **3**  - smallest possible
> difference in sums

Explanation:

> First subarray = {5, 13, 14}
> Second subarray = {8, 27}
> Difference in sums: abs((5+13+14)-(8+27)) = 3 = **min**

I have a guess that it's something connected to the binary search but I have no clue what is being "binary seached" and what to connect it to.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the optimization version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and if it was solvable efficiently, that would mean that $P = NP$. That means it is unlikely that there is a polynomial time solution to split an array in two.

There are [exact solution algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Exact_algorithms) described on the wikipedia page, and some of them are in pseudo-polynomial time.